# Query not performing well when calling multiple functions in one Update, but good performance when using multiple Updates

Tags: sql-server, performance

currently I've got the following question:
I've got an UPDATE Statement that updates a couple of records with the results of SELECT/COUNT(*)-Functions.

For example

```
UPDATE Table
SET Field1 = Function1(...),
Field2 = Function2(...),
Field3 = Function3(...)
```

This Query takes hours. 
But if I do it like that:

```
UPDATE Table
SET Field1 = Function1(...)

UPDATE Table
SET Field2 = Function2(...)

UPDATE Table
SET Field3 = Function3(...)
```

It finishes within less than an hour.

I searched the net and found some things related to Parameter Sniffing which seemed relevant to my problem. So I added a OPTION (RECOMPILE) to all my functions which helped a bit with performance but not much.
Does anyone know why this happens? I could obviously just stick to the multiple UPDATE statements but I still wonder why this even happens. Any ideas?

Edit: The functions are Scalar Functions

Comment: are these Scalar functions ?

Comment: it would help to see the tsql for the functions.

Comment: @M.Ali Yes, they are Scalar functions

Comment: For any SQL performance problems you need to check execution plans initially

Comment: Show us your code. Avoid using scalar functions.

Answer (score 3):

Re-write your scalar functions as table valued functions.

> Avoiding Row-by-Row Behavior with TVFs
>
> One of the problems with scalar functions is that they are executed once for every row in the result set. While this is not a problem for small result sets, it becomes a problem when our queries return a large number of rows. We can use TVFs to solve this problem.

- [SQL Server Functions: The Basics - Jeremiah Peschka](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-functions-the-basics/)

---

more references:

- [Scalar functions, inlining, and performance: An entertaining title for a boring post - Adam Machanic](http://dataeducation.com/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post/)
- [Why Scalar Functions Can Be Costly - Mickey Stuewe](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/135321/)
- [Inline Scalar Functions - Itzik Ben-Gan](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/inline-scalar-functions)

---

If you are getting `count(*)` for entire tables to track total rows, an alternative would be to use system views to get the row counts instead of executing `select count(*) from t` for each table.

```
select 
    [schema] = object_schema_name(o.object_id)
  , [table] = o.name
  , [index] = i.name
  , p.partition_number
  , [row_count] = p.rows
  , [index_type] = i.type_desc
from sys.partitions p
  inner join sys.indexes i 
    on p.object_id = i.object_id
      and p.index_id = i.index_id
      and i.index_id < 2
  inner join sys.objects o
    on i.object_id = o.object_id
where o.is_ms_shipped=0
--order by schema, table, index
```

Which returns this on rextester: http://rextester.com/URW59373

```
+--------+-------------------+----------------------+------------------+-----------+------------+
| schema |       table       |        index         | partition_number | row_count | index_type |
+--------+-------------------+----------------------+------------------+-----------+------------+
| dbo    | Pilots            | PK_Pilots            |                1 |         3 | CLUSTERED  |
| dbo    | Planes            | PK_Planes            |                1 |         2 | CLUSTERED  |
| dbo    | Flights           | PK_Flights           |                1 |         2 | CLUSTERED  |
| dbo    | Pilots_on_flights | PK_Pilots_on_flights |                1 |         4 | CLUSTERED  |
| dbo    | table1            | NULL                 |                1 |         0 | HEAP       |
| dbo    | table2            | NULL                 |                1 |         0 | HEAP       |
+--------+-------------------+----------------------+------------------+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: is right.  Scalar functions are bad for batch processes in general.  They should be reserved for setting variables or instances where you know with absolute certainty that there will be few rows.